# How to position my navbar on top of my slider?

Tags: css, layout, positioning, nav

Fairly new to this site as well as to coding and I'm trying to get around this problem I am having with my navigation bar. I am trying to go for a look similar to that of this website http://www.juxtapoz.com. I've basically got the opacity part down for my navigation bar and I just want to know how do I position it on top of my slider like the one shown on the link above and not above the slider. I hope that made sense.

Comment: Put in your code to show what have you done so far and then people willing to help will get clearer understanding and good head start to begin with solution to your problem.

Comment: @TheRohanSanap is right. Add some more details to your question so tat we can help you. Maybe creating a fiddle, too, wouldn't be a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap then all you have to do is add "`navbar-fixed-top`" something like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what slider you are talking about, but if it's only about the position of the nav bar, it should be fixed. When it's fixed it's like an absolute position, so you need to add this to your CSS code :

```
.nav{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:[your choice in px or em];
    background: RGBA(0,0,0,0.7);
    z-index:2;  //important to get the navigation over all other contents.
}
```